# Password protect gzip file using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, gzip

I want to password protect a gzip file generated using mysqldump.

`mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name | gzip > db_backup.sql.gz`

any ideas how to? would be better if i can achieve this using a one-line command.

P.S: using Nodejs to execute child process.

Comment: `gzip` does not support password protection

Comment: You can use openssl, gpg, etc. to encrypt a file.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but the below should work:

Create a key

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mysqldump-secure.priv.pem -out mysqldump-secure.pub.pem
```

Use the public key to encrypt

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name | gzip -c | openssl smime -encrypt -binary -text -aes256 -out db_backup.sql.gz.enc -outform DER mysqldump-secure.pub.pem
```

Use the key the decrypt

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in db_backup.sql.gz.enc -binary -inform DEM -inkey mysqldump-secure.priv.pem -out db_backup.sql.gz
```

Source: https://www.everythingcli.org/secure-mysqldump-script-with-encryption-and-compression/